# N=4 Superconformal Algebra

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lie-algebra

The following is related to the article "Review of AdS/CFT Integrability, Chapter VI.1: Superconformal Symmetry" [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.4004.pdf)

The superconformal group is ${\rm PSU}(2,2|4)$ with corresponding Lie algebra $\mathfrak{psu}(2,2|4)$

> In physical models, multiplets of states transform under
>   unitary representations of the symmetry algebra.

**Question**: Perhaps this is just confusion arising from the physicist convention of using groups and algebras interchangeably, but shouldn't we be looking for unitary representations of the **group**, or rather its universal cover, instead of the algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is meant is that the algebra is the set of transformations, called derivations sometimes, which define a unitary group. The elementary case is where Hermitean operators generate unitary groups. This is seen with $U~=~e^{-iHt/\hbar}$ so that $U^\dagger U~=~1$ for the parameter or time very small we have $U~\simeq~1~-~iHt/\hbar$ then 
$$
U^\dagger U~=~1~+~i(H^\dagger~-~H)t/\hbar~+~O(t^2).
$$
The $O(t)$ term must be zero which means $H^\dagger~=~H$.

I am not sure what level of answer is needed here. The projective group $PSU(2,2|4)$ is graded and has signature $+,+,-,-$ on its rank. The algebra then involve Bogoliubov or related transformations that in a sense make the group unitary.